# node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr/toast-noanimation.component.d.ts(19,9)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

shared.module.ts

```
import { animate, state, style, transition, trigger } from '@angular/animations';
import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [HeaderComponent, SidebarComponent],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule,
        FormsModule,
        NgxDatatableModule,
        ToastrModule.forRoot() // ToastrModule added
    ],
    exports: [
        HeaderComponent,
        SidebarComponent,
        FormsModule,
        NgxDatatableModule,
        ToastrModule,
    ],
    providers: []
})
```

this is my shared module 
i have installed 
npm install ngx-toastr --save
npm install @angular/animations --save

But it gives me an error

ERROR in node_modules/@angular/animations/browser/browser.d.ts(135,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
    node_modules/@angular/animations/browser/browser.d.ts(301,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
    node_modules/ngx-toastr/portal/portal.d.ts(26,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
    node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr/toast-noanimation.component.d.ts(19,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
    node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr/toast.component.d.ts(26,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

Please suggest for this

package.json file

```
{
  "name": "mop",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/material": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.12.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.2.1",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^16.0.3",
    "angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "line-awesome": "^1.3.0",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.6.3",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^2.3.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^12.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "save": "^2.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.23",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.23",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: i think those answers that have greater than 10 upvotes is better to accept.. please change if you thinking like me

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I had the same issue. I've solve it by changing the toastr version in the package.json. I've used this "ngx-toastr": "^10.0.4", instead of this "ngx-toastr": "^12.0.0". And then npm i.

Answer (score 16):

You just need to check that you are using the correct version of ngx-toastr for the version of Angular you are using.

```
ngx-toastr  Angular
6.5.0       4.x
8.10.2      5.x
10.1.0      8.x 7.x 6.x
11.3.3      8.x current >= 9.x
```

See the dependencies here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-toastr#dependencies

Answer (score 6):

Installed 
"ngx-toastr": "^10.0.4" and 
"@angular/animations": "^8.2.14",

For angular 8 permanently fixed my issue.

Answer (score 5):

**This issue may arise if your angular version and toastr version you installed do not match**

Dependencies

```
ngx-toastr  |   Angular version
-------------------------------------
6.5.0       |   4.x

8.10.2      |   5.x

10.1.0      |   8.x 7.x 6.x

11.3.3      |   8.x

12.1.0      |   9.x

current     |   >= 10.x
```

so for example, if you are using angular 4 x then you should install toastr version 6.5.0 anything more than 6.5.0 might give you an error

**How to install toastr particular version?**
if you have any toastr version already installed then uninstall it by

```
npm uninstall ngx-toastr
```

then install a particular version of toaster according to your angular version

```
npm install ngx-toastr@Your_version_number
```

**note: Also check Your @angular/animations version compatibility if issue still persists**
visit: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-toastr#dependencies for more information

Answer (score 2):

Please check your `package.json`, you may be using wrong version of

`@angular...` packages, some of them are ~9 and some of them are ~8

#### upgrade Angular by running:

```
ng update @angular/core @angular/cli
```

#### upgrade material

```
ng update @angular/material
```

You can also update manually the version in `package.json` and run `npm install` or `yarn`

Comment: i am not using material

Comment: Please share your package.json

Comment: As I mentioned you have "@angular/animations":  with version 9, and all other angular versions are ~8, please align to 8 or 9 and it will fix your issue